# how to forbid assignment to not reference variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, initialization, c++14

I fear it's a dumb question but...

Someone can suggest me a way to force that a return value from a function (or a method), that return a reference to an internal static variable or a member of the class/struct, is assigned only to **reference** variables ?

I try to explain what I desire with a minimal example.

Given the following code, with a function `wrapValue()` that return a reference to the internal static variable,

```
int & wrapValue (int v0)
 {
   static int val;

   return val = v0;
 }

int main ()
 {
   // how to permit this ...
   int & v0 { wrapValue(0) };

   // ... but forbid this ...
   int   v1 { wrapValue(1) };

   int   v2;

   // ... and this ?
   v2 = wrapValue(2);
 }
```

there is a way to permit the initialization of `v0` (and bound `v0` to the static variable) and forbid the initialization of `v1` and the assignment of `v2` (without bounding `v1` and `v2` to the static variable) ?

And if it's impossible with the current C++ standard, as I fear, someone can suggest me an alternative way (but not too complex: I intend use it in a library that I want to maintain simple) to forbid an unbounded assignment ?

Comment: Why do you want to? Isn't it up to your callers what they do with your return value?

Comment: Perhaps you don't want the value to be copied, only moved and constructed? Or perhaps not even moved?

Comment: @AlanStokes - The problem is that if the user puts the value, returned by a method I've developed (a class for options from argc/argv values parsing), in a simple (non reference) value, looses the value that, next, will be parsed. Maybe it's a dumb idea but seems working well *if* the user remember the `&`. I'm bad with English so for me it's difficult to explain... If you're interested (it's correct, according the Stack Overflow rules?), I can write the link to my github project.

Comment: @flatmouse - My real problem is more complex and involve templates and virtual methods; briefly, what i want is save a reference to a variable, internal to a instance of a class, that is created when the method is called; if the user forget the `&`, the reference is lost and the value (that is set in a following phase) is lost; maybe my solution is a dumb one, but seems working if the user remember the `&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is somewhat tricky but it works (I think) as you expect:

```
#include <iostream>

struct int_wrapper {
    int value;
    int_wrapper &operator=(int value) {
        this->value = value;
        return *this;
    }
    operator int&() {
        return value;
    }
    operator int() {
        return value;
    }
};

int_wrapper& wrapValue (int v0) {
   static int_wrapper val;
   return val = v0;
}

int main () {
   // how to permit this ...
   int & v0 = wrapValue(0);

   // ... but forbid this ...
   //int   v1 { wrapValue(1) }; // call ambigious

   int   v2;
   (void)v0;
   (void)v2;

   // ... and this ?
   //v2 = wrapValue(2); // call ambigious
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3xKEof3EYUdcRLIh)

Comment: Tricky but simple to use and nice. My real problem involves templates but should be simple modify your `int_wrapper` in a template wrapper. I'll try but ... +1 for the moment.

Comment: @max66 I'm not sure why but this solution disallow to initialization of reference by brace enclose initializer e.g. `int &v0{wrapValue(0)};` (ambiguity just like in case of values?). On the other hand `int &v0(wrapValue(0));` does not cause ambiguity... Don't know how to interpret that...

Comment: Interesting; so do I (I don't know how to interpret that...); I suppose you should open a question :)

Comment: [done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079111/why-does-aggregate-initialization-causes-ambiguity-for-type-reference-cast-if-ca)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know int is copyable, so people can copy if they like; you cannot prevent this. However, you could create a wrapper class that is non-copyable.

```
class NonCopyableInt
{
    int val;
public:
    NonCopyableInt(int val) : val(val) {}
    NonCopyableInt(NonCopyableInt&) = delete;
    int& value() { return val; }
    // todo: add some nice operators and functions such as assignment from int
}

NonCopyableInt& wrapValue (int v0)
{
    static NonCopyableInt val;
    return val = v0;
}
```

However, people could always copy the return value from value() so you end up with the same problem. And it feels really clunky and meh.