# Why does direct list initialization causes ambiguity for type reference cast if cast operators to the type and reference to the type are declared?

Tags: c++, ambiguity, list-initialization, typecast-operator

The question rose in context of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41076678/4324224).

Consider an example:

```
struct foo {
    int value;
    operator int&(){ return value; }
    operator int(){ return value; }
};

int main () {
    int &a(foo{}); // #1
    //int &b{foo{}}; // #2 -- ambiguity
    int &c = foo{}; // #3
    //int &d = {foo{}}; // #4-- ambiguity
    int &d { a }; // #5
    int &e = { a }; // #6
    (void)a;
    (void)c;
    (void)d;
    (void)e;
}
```

I don't understand why does #2 and #4 cause ambiguity while #1 and #3 does not. So the question is - why does direct list initialization causes ambiguity for implicit cast to reference if cast operators to the type and reference to the type are declared?

Comment: `int &a(foo{})` is direct initialization. `int &b{foo{}}` is direct *list* initialization. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List initialization, when used to initialize a reference, will take the listed values and convert them into a prvalue (aka: a temporary), which will be used to direct initialize the reference.

So `int &b{foo{}}` is functionally equivalent to `int &b(int(foo{}))`. Which is ambiguous; it could generate that `int` via `operator int` or `operator int&`.

But even if it wasn't ambiguous, you would still be getting a non-const lvalue reference to a prvalue. Which is illegal. So this code was *never* going to work.

Braced-init-lists (curly braces) initialize *objects*, not *references* to objects. If you already have an object and want to get a reference to it, don't use braced-init-lists.

---

> But in this case why does compiler accept #5?

Because list initialization is a series of rules with priority. A rule that has a higher priority than the one I pointed out above is the case of a braced-init-list which contains a single value, who's type is identical to the type of what is being initialized. #5 and 6 just so happen to fit that bill, since `d`, `e`, and `a` are all `int&`s.

But if you just take my advice and not use braced-init-lists when you're not trying to create an object, you won't have to worry about corner-cases like that.

Comment: As not everyone knows about prvalue (for instance, myself). Here is the link to its explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3601661/783510

Comment: But in this case why does compiler accept #5? isn't it similarly equivalent to `int &d(int(a));`?

Comment: @NicolBolas that answers my question exhaustively! Thanks!

Comment: "Braced-init-lists (curly braces) initialize objects, not references to objects.", that's a bit too much of a simplification. There's no problem with `int a = 0; int &b {a};` where it initializes a reference.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It's a simplification yes, but a very useful one. It avoids corner-cases like the above.